# Multi-Column, Multi-row vertical and horizontally aligned using CSS3 or flex-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't seem to find a way to build this without javascript or hacky markup. I have columns of data that need to respond to the amount of text in a neighboring column. There will be four columns horizontally across the page. If there are more than 4 entries, the columns should wrap and just as before, adjust the heights of each cell to the tallest neighboring cell. I can't really do this in a table because the design should be responsive and eventually drop to a 2 column per row then one.

I am not so sure flex-box will do what I want either being that the height of each row is dependent upon a neighboring column. The vertical space can be filled evenly, but the cells will not necessarily line up horizontally.

[Link to what I am trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKHYu.png)

Apologies if the problem is hard to follow. Will post additional images if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box; font-family: sans-serif;}

#container {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 400px;  
  
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    /*align-items: center; | Don't use*/ 
}

.row {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: 24%;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    margin: 1%;
    margin-left: 0;
    max-width: 24%;
  
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

header {
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #3498DB;
  color: #fff;
}

section {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #E74C3C;
  color: #fff;
  
  flex: 1;
}

aside {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #7F8C8D;
  color: #fff;
}

footer {
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #34495E;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="row">
            <header>header / Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</header>
            <section>section / Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde aliquid dolores est perferendis, voluptates delectus, quidem fugiat alias ullam voluptas sit voluptatibus ipsam similique nulla, doloremque sequi accusamus id provident.</section>
            <aside>aside</aside>
            <footer>footer</footer>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <header>header</header>
            <section>section</section>
            <aside>aside</aside>
            <footer>footer</footer>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <header>header</header>
            <section>section</section>
            <aside>aside</aside>
            <footer>footer</footer>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <header>header</header>
            <section>section</section>
            <aside>aside</aside>
            <footer>footer</footer>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <header>header</header>
            <section>section</section>
            <aside>aside</aside>
            <footer>footer</footer>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <header>header</header>
            <section>section / Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde aliquid dolores est perferendis, voluptates delectus.</section>
            <aside>aside</aside>
            <footer>footer</footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you for the response, this is close to what I need, but also I am looking to align the header, section, aside, and footer's starting and ending points. In essence, setting the height of all elements to the largest one in that grouping of 4 "rows". I am not sure it is possible with flexbox or any css for that matter. [example showing what is produced vs desired result](http://i.imgur.com/Iw2GCca.png)

Comment: I think you can't do that with CSS, you need to use Javascript to copy the height from the primary row and apply them in the others rows.